# Mongo Query Parser Regex

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

i want to extract query part(name,find,sort,limit - split by dot(.))  from mongo query via regex

input - >

```
 db.metrics.find(
        {
        "brand_name":"Apple",
        "job_status.status":"SUCCESS",
        'host.user':'root',
        "current_time":{$gt:new Date(Date.now() - 3*60*60 * 1000)}
        }
    ).sort({"current_time" : -1}).limit(10)
```

with help of 2-3 stackoverflow answer i have build below regex

```
regex = `\.(?=(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)(?![^()]*\\)`
```

which solves my use case till certain extent 
i am not able to ignore dot(.) char group inside curly braces (Date.now())

[regExr.com matched screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqlgP.png)

i need regex which should ignore .now() part from above query

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON parser ?

Comment: i am doing this in java , it only parses json string to Document only below part it wil parse ,{
        "brand_name":"Apple",
        "job_status.status":"SUCCESS",
        'host.user':'root',
        "current_time":{$gt:new Date(Date.now() - 3*60*60 * 1000)}
        }